# Ruby on Rails/will_paginate: Ordering by custom columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I've got a rather complicated SQL-Query whose results should be paginated and displayed to the user. I don't want to go into details here, but to put it simple I just select all columns of a model, **and an additional column**, that is used just for sorting purposes.

```
Note.select( ['notes.*', "<rather complicated clause> AS 'x'"] ).joins(...)...
```

After some `.join()'s` and a `.group()`, I finally call `.order()` and `.paginate` on the relation. If I order by any of the model's natural columns everything works fine, if I however order by the "artificial" column `x`, rails gives me the error:

```
no such column: x
```

This seems to occur because will_paginate seems to do a `COUNT(*)`-statement before getting the actual data, simply to get the amounts of data it has to process. This `COUNT(*)`-statement is (of course) generated from the original statement, which includes the `ORDER BY x`. The problem now is, that will_paginate keeps the `ORDER BY` in the statement but simply replaces the column definitions with `COUNT(*)` and thus cannot find the column `x`.

Using `Rails 3` and `will_paginate 3.0.pre2`.

Is there any way to get around this?

thx for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the initial count query by passing in the value manually:

```
total_entries = Note.select(...).joins(...).count
Note.select( ... ).joins(...).group().paginate(:total_entries => total_entries)
```

The above is not a literal code sample and you may need to tweak your count query to get the correct results for your join.  This should let you do a straight up complex query on the pagination.