# will_paginate, includes, and ordering by a joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

So, I'm doing something like:

```
 user.students.includes(:exams).ungraded.paginate(:page =>
   params[:page]).order("exams.created_at desc")
```

However, this causes a subtle problem.  Somewhere in the guts of active record, the limit makes it do a distinct on the student id's, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "students".id, exams.id AS alias_0 FROM "students" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "exams" ON "exams"."student_id" = "students"."id"
WHERE "students"."ready_for_grading" = 't' ORDER BY exams.id LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

However, this may cause results like:

```
 id | alias_0 
----+---------
 42 |     256
 42 |     257
 42 |     260
```

See the problem?  Eventually the limit kicks in and we don't fetch as many student id's as we were supposed to because we've "used them up" by selecting both the student id's and the exam ids, even though we really only want the exam id's for ordering.

This is Rails 3.2.1, and PostgreSQL 9.1.

**Edit**

I think what is happening is that paginate is using the query to get a list of students, which it then feeds to a second query, but because of the left outer join, we're not getting distinct results for the students, so it 'underfills' the 10 slots we have and generally confuses things.  I think this is a bug somewhere, but I'm not sure who to pin it on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out:

```
user.students.joins("left outer join exams on exams.student_id = students.id").ungraded.paginate(:page =>
   params[:page]).order("exams.created_at desc")
```

Seems to work.  I'm not sure why this works out better than using 'includes', but it does.

Comment: I used this related one to solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283724/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-ordering-by-custom-columns